# Get all folders and files in a directory

Tags: java, android

i have this directory:

/mnt/sdcard/App/Downloads/Files/Documents/ as the root directory or folder of my app. the said directory contains other set of folder and files which i need to show the folder, subfolder and files exact paths in the Logcat.

how can i do that without needing to click anything in the view, just on launch, the exact paths will show up in the Logcat.

Comment: After reading your question again, I am not sure what you mean by it being your "root" directory.  Are you talking in the context of an app, and you want to do this programmatically, or are you just needing some sort of access/listing of the files?  My answer should achieve the latter.

Comment: i'm kinda new to Android and i'm making an app where i need to access this directory in sdcard and list all folders, subfolders and files inside it like a file explorer

Answer (score 0):

You can run

> adb shell

From there, you can cd and ls like on any Linux machine.  Since your files are on the sdcard, you probably won't have permissions issues like when trying to access the /data folder when not root.